# How to play audio files when extracting a .jar?

Tags: java, url, audio, applet, embedded-resource

I want to make an app in Java that will play a sound every time a button is pressed. It works, but only when I open it in Eclipse. When I extract it, it doesn't play a sound. 
I think the code needs to be written using URL, however, I'm having trouble making it work and I haven't found a solution online. My audio files are in res directory which is in src directory. 
Example of a button:

```
JButton btnEngleski = new JButton("Engleski");
    btnEngleski.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Ucitaj.Zvuk("C:\\Users\\eclipse-workspace\\Hello Soundboard\\src\\resources\\Engleski.wav");
        }
    });
```

This is method Zvuk which is used to load a sound and play it

```
public void Zvuk(String imeZvuka)
 {
  try 
  {
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(imeZvuka).getAbsoluteFile( ));
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip( );
clip.open(audioInputStream);
clip.start( );
 }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    System.out.println("Greška.");
    ex.printStackTrace( );
 }
}
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: First thing to verify; are the sound files being included in your JAR (JARs are just zipped files; open it using something like tar or 7z).  If your sound files are not being included, then they cannot be referenced (unless using absolute pathing on the machine that has be pre-configured, or relative pathing if run from the expected path, but either way this is not good; they should be in the JAR so that they can be referenced from any machine).

Comment: Also, please include some sample code that outlines the behavior.  At minimum, the code that is both calling the sound effect and loading it from a file, but it is *vastly* preferable to have an [MCVE].

Comment: It's a runnable JAR and absolute pathing is no good as I need the app to work on other PCs.

Comment: `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource("/Engleski.wav"))` will read the file, regardless of whether you’re running from a .jar or not.  Never assume a resource is separate physical file.

Comment: @VGR makes a good point. See the [embedded-resource info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for further details.